# Does Kubernetes support persistent volumes shared between multiple nodes in a cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, persistent-storage

I need to build an application that has many **bare-metal** nodes joined in a Kubernetes cluster and I need a shared persistent file system between those **nodes**. The nodes should be able to read-write in this file system simultaneously.

Bonus: is there a way to keep the file system alive even if the cluster crashes?

I read [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) article but cant find answers to this question.

This problem is very important to me because it is a requirement to my undergraduate paper.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes it does. What you're looking for is to set your AccessMode to `ReadWriteMany`.
Note that not all Volume Plugins provide `ReadWriteMany`.

Multiple pods might be reading/writing to the Volume plugin at the same time. If a node/pod were to restart, you would still have access to the volume.

To get a full list of what which Volume Plugin supports that, refer to the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes).